# Custom Google login page

Tags: google-sites, google-signin

You all know this page.. Is there **ANY** way to customize this page somehow?

1. I thought using an iframe and custom the HTML but Google won't let
   me embed their websites..
2. I thought using a Google Site and inserting a login gadget but there
       is no login gadget.

What  I want is a custom page where my clients can login to their gmail, drive....

What I want it's not impossible, this guys http://www.cloudcodes.com/custom-login-page.html offers you the possibility to custom the login page and even redirect you to another page after you've logged in.

[image]

Comment: No you can't. Jesus, think of it, it would be so easy to phish some delicious Google Accounts. I think some years ago you could upload a custom company image on Google Apps Business.

Comment: @stackiflow111 you still are able to upload a custom logo using Google Apps for Business but thats all.. I just wanted to customize it a little adding backgroud, widgets.....

Comment: unfortunately, as @stackiflow111 pointed out, if they let you do that, it would be way too easy to phish. I don't think you can. You can :(

Comment: What I want it's not impossible, this guys http://www.cloudcodes.com/custom-login-page.html offers you the possibility to custom the login page and even redirect you to another page after you've logged in. @Julldar

Comment: Interesting, I was unaware of that. I'll look into it then :p it is something I would like to do as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Directly editing the native login page at accounts.google.com is not possible.

However, for [Google Apps](http://www.google.com/enterprise/apps/business/) accounts, you have the option to set up the [Single Sign On](https://support.google.com/a/answer/60224?hl=en) service, which allows you to authenticate through a third party provider (Or yourself, if you have the ability). What GControl are offering is this service, although they've labeled it misleadingly, to make you believe your actually editing the login page, rather than redirecting your users to a secure login.

They do it very well though, leveraging the Google Apps APIs to allow you to write and setup the service in their own console.

Source: I installed the service and tried their free trial, and they simply used the APIs to enable SSO on my domain. [image: SSO Turned on]

Edit for clarity: SSO setup is not available for consumer Gmail.com accounts.